# Facebook api inviting friends to website of 50 per request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to invite facebook friends to my website.Facebook allows only 50 requests to be sent in one batch.So i want to make a UI to display this batch request made by the facebook for inviting every 50 request.How this could be done.

Comment: You are looking for a way to bypass the 50 user request limit?

Comment: SO is a place to help you overcome certain problems, not to write code for you. Try something yourself, see what kind of problems you run into and then ask

Comment: No , how to make users know that still they need to send to remaining of their friends. Sites like branchout.com shows it with a progress bar.How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you are looking for.

http://www.webtuts.info/webdevelopment/facebook-api-invite-friends-website/172/